# iOS CallKit - no 'missed call notifications'

Tags: ios, notifications, callkit

I am using CallKit, and it is working fine, it calls on my phone properly, I can answer and deny it.

The problem is there is no 'missed call' notification when I do not answer it. 
Is there any setting in CallKit that toggles it?

Comment: Did you find any solution..?

Answer (score 1):

We were also facing the same issues, and the solution was to manage UILocalNotifications yourself. CallKit only provides triggers and callbacks for events.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the method reportCall(with:endedAt:reason) on CXProvider.  You can specify the end reason to let CallKit know why the call ended.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider/1930701-reportcall

The reasons include:

- case failed - An error occurred while attempting to service the call.
- case remoteEnded - The remote party explicitly ended the call.
- case unanswered - The call never started connecting and was never
  explicitly ended,  such as when an outgoing or incoming call times
  out.
- case answeredElsewhere - Another device answered the call.
- case declinedElsewhere - Another device declined the call.

If you call reportCall with a reason of unanswered, then it will show up as a missed call in the recent calls section of the phone app.

Comment: OP was referring specifically to "notifications", not the call-log. A key behaviour of notifications, is that they can make your phone vibrate - which is important to notify a user of a missed call without them having to look at their screen. See the answer from @varunrathi28

Comment: My intention was to explain how to set a call as missed so that the user will know that they missed a call.  iOS doesn't post notifications when you miss a call with the phone app.  I don't know why you would do this in your own app.  CallKit is designed to make the user experience the same across all calling apps.